# Can't fill table from view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Probably a ferry easy (stupid) question, but i am stuck four a couple of hours now. I have search many items on SO, but i don't know what i am doing wrong.
I recently started development for IOS.

What i am trying to do: I have a Utility application with a table inside the mainview. I tried to fill the table dynamicly with code.

.h file

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *JSONArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSArray *JSONArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSArray *dynamicTable;

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface MainViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize JSONArray;
@synthesize tableview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableview.delegate = self;

    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];  

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableview reloadData];
    });
}
```

To fill the table i used the default IOS example (bellow the post)

When I start the app, the numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath , etc... doesn't load. What a I doing wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:  (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to set the class as datasource. Try with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableview.delegate = self;
    self.tableview.datasource = self;  // <-- You forgot this

    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];

    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put the datasource delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableview setDataSource:self];
```

There are actually two delegates for a TableView one used to deal with the data and the other one to deal with interactions with the table view.